# Correlation between grand mean and Individual mean in r

Tags: r, subset, correlation, mean

I got two data sets from the same raw data set:
First one is Grand_Mean which is mean TechnicalQuality score for each impairment type across all participants:

```
impairment <- c ("H0", "H1", "H2", "H3",  "H4")
TechnicalQuality <- c(4.216667, 3.475000, 3.375000, 3.100000, 2.250000)
Grand_Mean <-data.frame( impairment = impairment,
                 TechnicalQuality = TechnicalQuality)
```

The second one is P_TQ_Mean which has mean technicalQuality score for each impairment per participant: (here I just attached 2 participant as samples)

```
P_impairment<-c ("H0", "H1", "H2", "H3",  "H4", "H0", "H1", "H2", "H3",  "H4")
Participant<-c("A01", "A01", "A01", "A01", "A01", "A02", "A02", "A02","A02","A02")
P_TechnicalQuality<-c(4.222222, 2.250000, 2.750000, 1.666667, 1.500000, 4.111111, 2.500000, 2.000000, 2.000000, 2.000000)
P_TQ_Mean<-data.frame(Participant= Participant, P_impairment= P_impairment, P_TechnicalQuality= P_TechnicalQuality)
```

I need calculate correlation between Grand_Mean's TechinicalQuality score and P_TQ_Mean's P_TechnicalQuality Score to see the correlation between sample population and each individual so that I can identify which one is outlier based on the result.

Is there any nice way to create a new data set shows the correlation result instead of doing it manually one by one?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an approach:

```
# Create matrix of the scores (one column per participant)
mat <- matrix(P_TQ_Mean$P_TechnicalQuality, nrow = nrow(Grand_Mean))

# calculate correlation with scores in `GrandMean`
corrs <- cor(mat, Grand_Mean$TechnicalQuality)

# create a data frame with the results
data.frame(unique(P_TQ_Mean["Participant"]), cor = corrs)
#   Participant       cor
# 1         A01 0.8911985
# 6         A02 0.7955540
```